# Как использовать php функции в Jquery .append?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, append

Добрый день, реализовал lazy load ленту, которая по мере прокрутки страницы подгружает новости. Используется самописный движок на Codeigniter 3.
 
Все работает, проблема заключается в том, что в
`$("#posts").append('');`
необходимо вставить большую конструкцию верстки вперемешку с php функциями самого Codeigniter.
Например, массив data содержит дату новости в формате unix_timestamp.. пробую вывести ее используя родную функцию Codeignter:

```
$.each(data, function(index, data){
    $("#posts").append('<?php unix_to_human( + data.created + )?>');
                        });
```

Такой вывод не работает. Каким образом можно в append засунуть такой сложный вывод используя php теги?

P.S. Полный код привожу ниже:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var inProcess = false;
    var num = 15;


    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() && !inProcess) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://домен/lazy/index',
                method: 'GET',
                data: {"num" : num},
                beforeSend: function() {
                    inProcess = true;
                }
            }).done(function(data){
                data = JSON.stringify(data);
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $.each(data, function(index, data){
                        $("#posts").append(''); // вывод контента тут
                    });

                    inProcess = false;
                    num += 15;
                }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, вы не можете вызывать ПХП-функции внутри Джаваскрипта после того, как ваш файл полностью выполнил свою работу (т.е., страница была загружена браузером).

В вашем случае я вижу 2 варианта воплощения задуманного:

1. Возвращать с сервера уже преобразованные нужным образом данные (рекомендуемый способ, сервер для этого и нужен);
2. Продублировать в Джаваскрипте используемые вами ПХП-функции и вызывать их.

Answer (score -1):

В вашем примере код php выполняется, но не выводится в браузер.
Попробуйте добавить функцию вывода.

```js
$.each(data, function(index, data){

    $("#posts").append('<?php echo unix_to_human( + data.created + )?>');

                        });
```

Если это то что вам нужно. Но лучше реализовать отдельный скрипт php для формирования необходимой верстки динамически и уже обращаться к нему.